# How to open rails project after setting it up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I had just installed rails gem and I did `rails new nameOfProject`.

After I setup my project I went to `localhost:3000` to check the main page but the browser wrote the unable to connect .

So I checked in terminal `telnet localhost 3000` and still not responding .

Where is the problem here ?

Comment: do `cd project_name` and then `rails s`

Comment: @user123 Rails responded : http://pastebin.com/njqiyN5r

Comment: which ruby version you are using?

Comment: do `rvm reinstall 1.9.3` and then `gem install rails`

Comment: @user123 `ruby 1.9.3p484 `

Comment: do as I have mentioned and then try

Comment: Start your rails server using the command `rails s`. And then try localhost:3000

Comment: do `rvm list` and `rvm gemset list` and give me your results.

Answer (score 0):

- `cd nameOfProject`
- `rvm gemset create nameOfProject`
- `rvm use 1.9.3p484@nameOfProject`
- `gem install bundler`
- `bundle install`
- `rails s`

If any problem comment here.